# Pandas column A > B, execute trade with Zipline

Tags: python, pandas, zipline

I have a problem trying to backtest a financial idea I've got with Zipline.

What I've got is closing price for SPY in the first column data['SPY'], and a "homemade" signal data['Signal']. The signal works similar to a moving average, and is either below or above data['SPY'].

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
```

Now the trading logic is not working, since if I understand it correctly, pandas does not make computations by rows but instead computes on the whole dataset at once.

```
    def handle_data(self, data):
    if data['SPY'] - data['Signal'] > 0:
        self.order('SPY', 1)
    else:
        self.order('SPY', -1)
```

The non-working code above express the logic that I want to perform -- if SPY > Signal then buy, sell if the opposite is true. I've tried all kinds of iterations but just can't make it work.

Anyone that can help as struggling amateur trader out?

#

I managed to get a bit further. What I needed to do was to add a "transform" to my dataframe, in this case a Moving Average. Since I don't want to actually use a moving average, I set the number of days to 1, which in effect should mean that I use the original numbers.

```
class Test(TradingAlgorithm):
def initialize(self):
    self.add_transform(MovingAverage, 'dummy', ['price'], window_length=1) # The moving average that I don't really want to utilize.
    self.pos_long = False
    self.pos_short = False

def handle_data(self, data):
    if data['SPY'].dummy['price'] >= data['Signal'].dummy['price'] and not self.pos_long:
        self.order('SPY', 100)
        self.pos_long = True
        self.pos_short = False
    elif data['SPY'].dummy['price'] <= data['Signal'].dummy['price'] and not self.pos_short:
        self.order('SPY', -100)
        self.pos_long = False
        self.pos_short = True
```

The above code works almost exactly as I'd like, the only quirk is that for some reason it doesn't take any short positions. But it's at least a step in the right direction, and might help others out.

These two links below helped me figure this bit out.

http://zipline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/zipline.transforms.html

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/twiecki/financial-analysis-python-tutorial/blob/master/3.%20Backtesting%20using%20Zipline.ipynb

Comment: I think you need a small toy example (with desired result) of what this code is *supposed* to do. Hard to follow with just non-working code! Is a column like `data['buy'] = data['SPY'] - data['Signal']` helpful?

Comment: are these dfs the same size and indexed the same, you could just concatenate them together and then add the additional column

Comment: The problem if I understand it correctly, is how pandas operates on dataframes. What I'm trying to accomplish is for Zipline (the backtesting program built with python) to check for each date if my signal value is above or below the closing price of SPY. Zipline uses pandas, and thus does not iterate over each row in the dataframe, but instead calculates on the whole dataframe at once, resulting in an array of True and False statements. Unfortunately I can't iterate over these statements and execute my trading logic based on their boolean values.